# Typescript compiler failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, nativescript

i am using nativescript to develop mobile app project,
i ve used photoviewer plugin, and it works fine when debuging the app in my phone but when i try to publish the app, iget always this error

> Found peer TypeScript 3.1.6
>
> node_modules/nativescript-photoviewer/photoviewer.d.ts(48,22): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIColor'.
>
> node_modules/nativescript-photoviewer/photoviewer.d.ts(54,24): error
>    TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIColor'.
>
> node_modules/nativescript-photoviewer/photoviewer.d.ts(60,23): error
>    TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIColor'.
>
> node_modules/nativescript-photoviewer/photoviewer.d.ts(89,13): error
>    TS2304: Cannot find name 'UIImage'.
>
> node_modules/nativescript-photoviewer/photoviewer.d.ts(94,24): error
>    TS2304: >Cannot find name 'UIImage'. 
>   TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 1

i ve tried to delete hooks, node_modules and platform folder and rerun npm install but nothing works,
i ll be so gratefull if any one help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

on `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`

Or alternatively you could configure [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) plugin in your project.